# Проблема с компаратором

Tags: java

При прогоне некоторой программы с изменяющимися параметрами (параметры меняю по координатной сетке) с целью найти оптимальный набор параметров вылезает вот такая ошибка:

> Comparison method violates its general contract!

Интересным является то, что при прогоне по разному количесту точек сетки результат то есть, то вылетает вот такой баг. Где я допустил ошибку?

```
public class Request implements Comparable<Request>{

private int idRequest;
private int indexOfModelledProfile;
private Visitor Visitor = new Visitor();
private Region region = new Region();
private DateTime date = new DateTime();
private Site Site = new Site();

@Override
public int compareTo(Request request) {

    if ( date == null ) {
        if ( request.date != null ) {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    else {
        if ( request.date == null ) {
            return 1;
        }

        int res = date.compareTo(request.date);
        if ( res != 0 ) { 
            return res; 
        }
    }

    int requestId = request.getVisitor().getVisitorId();
    int id = Visitor.getVisitorId();
    if ( id > requestId ){ return 1;}
    else if ( id < requestId ){ return -1;}
    else if ( id == requestId ){

        if ( region == null ) {
            if ( request.getRegion() != null ) {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        else {
            if ( request.getRegion() == null ) {
                return 1;
            }

            if ( request.region.getValue() == null ){
                if ( region.getValue() != null ){
                    return -1;
                }
            }
            else {
                if ( region.getValue() == null ){
                    return 1;
                }
                else {
                    int res2 = request.region.getValue().compareTo(region.getValue()); 
                    if ( res2 == 1 ){ return 1;}
                    else if ( res2 == 0 ){ return 0;}
                    else { return -1; } 
                }   
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Это значит что вы не выполняете требования сравнения элементов. Они описаны http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)

Comment: Конкретно тут в чем косяк?

Comment: Да в первой же строке: 

    if ( request == null ) {
        return 1;
    }

Из [документации](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html): 

> Note that null is not an instance of any class, and `e.compareTo(null)` should throw a `NullPointerException` even though `e.equals(null)` returns `false`.

И ещё наверняка в других местах.

Comment: И случай, когда `this.date == null` и `request.date == null`, обрабатывается неправильно. Дальше не смотрел.

---
Стоп, тут наврал, смотрю дальше :-)

---
Остальное вроде правильно. Исправляйте первую строку.

Comment: @VladD, все-равно вылезает тот баг..

Comment: Хм, вот что ещё может быть проблемой:

    if ( res2 == 1 ){ return 1;}

Дело в том, что результат может быть любым числом больше 0. Попробуйте изменить это на

    if ( res2 > 0 ){ return 1;}

Comment: да, все заработало, спасибо!     
Почему-то был уверен, что compareTo возвращает ровно 1, а не что-то большее 0.     
Еще непонятно почему при прогоне небольшой координатной сетке все отрабатывает нормально, а при большей все падает.

Comment: Отлично, тогда сейчас сделаю ответ.

На небольшой сетке сортировке нужно меньше сравнений, и она случайно не натыкалась на проблему.

Comment: Сравнений на любой сетке нужно одинаковое количество.    
Вообще прогон модели - это генерация трафика(генерация тех самых request) с различных сайтов и сортировка их.     
Прогон по сетке здесь вообще никак не участвует.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Итак, есть две проблемы:

1)

```
if ( request == null ) {
    return 1;
}
```

противоречит [документации](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html):

> Note that `null` is not an instance of any class, and `e.compareTo(null`) should throw a NullPointerException even though `e.equals(null)` returns false.

2)

```
if ( res2 == 1 ){ return 1;}
```

Дело в том, что результат может быть любым числом больше 0. Этот код надо изменить на

```
if ( res2 > 0 ){ return 1;}
```

---

Вообще-то, ваш код неоправданно сложен. Вы должны делегировать сравнение нижележащим классам. В этом случае получится что-то такое:

```
static class CompareHelper {
    public static int <T extends Comparable<T>> int compare(T l, T r) {
        int lweight = l == null ? 0 : 1;
        int rweight = r == null ? 0 : 1;
        if (lweight == 1 && rweight == 1)
            return l.CompareTo(r);
        else
            return lweight - rweight;
    }
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Request request) {
    int result;
    if (((result = CompareHelper.compare(date, request.date)) != 0) ||
        ((result = CompareHelper.compare(getVisitor(), request.getVisitor())) != 0) ||
        ((result = CompareHelper.compare(getRegion(), request.getRegion())) != 0))
        return result;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Добрый вечер, вы писали что-то о подготовке к поступлению в ШАД. Я тоже поступаю в этом году и мы можем порешать какие-то задачи. К сожалению на этом дурацком сайте нет сообщений пользователю

Comment: Решайте, я уже там учусь..) если будут вопросы, то оставь свой скайп - спишемся